# sitemap.xml rewrite for multi domain site

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

on my magento multi domain site I wan't to rewrite root sitemap.xml file to language specific sitemap.xml.

Example:

```
domain.com -> domain.com/sitemaps/com/sitemap.xml
domain.it -> domain.com/sitemaps/it/sitemap.xml
domain.de -> domain.com/sitemaps/de/sitemap.xml
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `%{HTTP_HOST}` contains the hostname that was used for the request. Assuming all domain names point to the same www-root, put this in your .htaccess in your www-root.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain\.([a-z]+)$
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ /sitemaps/%1/sitemap.xml [L]
```